# Eclipse Memory Analyzer Explanation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Can someone explain to me what the black down arrows mean when trying to find leak suspects in the Eclipse Memory Analyzer?  Do they represent incoming references? For example, is the DateAxis object holding a reference to an array of Objects, which is holding a reference to many XYPlot objects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct. 
The arrow might either indicate a direct or indirect reference. 
I'm not sure what your screenshot shows, but in same cases it will indicates that one object "retains" the other one.

Answer (score 0):

actually that depends on which way you display the objects, "incoming" or "outgoing" , if you select "outgoing" on object **A**   , it will display all the objects that **A** has reference on